Computation of $\int _{-a}^a f(t)^j (1-f(t))^{m-j}\, dt$
Doing some research I face with this kind of integrals:
Given $a>0$, $m,j\in\mathbb{N}$ with $j\leq m$,
$$ I(a,j,m)= \int_{-a}^{+a} f(t)^j\cdot (1-f(t))^{m-j}\, dt $$
I'm interested in the case where $f$ is a polynomial of degree one. But if anyone knows something about this general family of integrals, please let me know. Could be a closed form or some properties...
Thanks in advance.

Rescale the linear function $f(t)$ so that it takes value $0$ at $-a$ and $1$ at $a$. Then use properties of Beta functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

$$
I(a,j,m)=\int_{-a}^a f^j(1-f)^{m-j} dt
=
\sum_{i=0}^{m-j}\binom{m-j}{i} (-)^i \int_{-a}^a f^{j+i} dt
$$
If in particular $f(t) = \alpha+\beta t$ with $\beta\neq 0$ then
$$
=
\sum_{i=0}^{m-j}\binom{m-j}{i} (-)^i \int_{-a}^a (\alpha+\beta t)^{j+i} dt
=
\sum_{i=0}^{m-j}\binom{m-j}{i} \frac{(-)^i}{\beta} \int_{\alpha-a\beta}^{\alpha+\beta a} x^{j+i} dx
$$
$$
=
\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i=0}^{m-j}\binom{m-j}{i} \frac{(-)^i}{j+i+1} [(\alpha+\beta a)^{j+i}-(\alpha -\beta a)^{j+i}].
$$
The interesting side aspect in this case is the sum rule
$$
\int_{-a}^a 1^m dt
=
2a
=
\int_{-a}^a (f+1-f)^m dt
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j} \int_{-a}^a  f^j (1-f)^{m-j} dt
=
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j} I(a,j,m).
$$
